# How do I remove text blocks within a log file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have the following log:

```
2016/01/20 00:00:16.035 [T114BaseServlet] ... Blah Blah Blah
2016/01/20 00:00:16.036 [ApplicationState] ... Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
2016/01/20 00:00:29.531 [T114BaseRequestPayloadParser] ... Blah Blah Blah
2016/01/20 00:00:36.036 [ApplicationState] ... Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
```

I want to remove those `ApplicationState` lines, but there's no pattern at the end of those `Blah Blah Blah`.

This is the block that I want to remove:

```
2016/01/20 00:00:16.036 [ApplicationState] ... Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
```

before the next request begins.

Comment: are there lines that you want to keep that contain the text "[ApplicationState]" ? a simple `grep -v` *could* be the answer...

Comment: @JeffSchaller - youre a smart guy.

Comment: This is the block that I want to remove:<br/>
<br/>
2016/01/20 00:00:16.036 [ApplicationState] ... Blah Blah Blah<br/>
Blah Blah Blah<br/>
Blah Blah Blah<br/>
Blah Blah Blah<br/>
Blah Blah Blah<br/>
<br/>
before the next request begins<br/>

Comment: `grep -v '\[ApplicationState\]' FileToStrip > StrippedFile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the whole block of lines beginning with one including your match up to the line occurring immediately previous to the next occurrence of `[T1114Base` you can do the following:

```
sed -e'$!N;/ApplicationState.*\n/,/\n.*\[T1114Base/!P;D' <in >out
```

It is fairly simple to understand how this works. By default `sed` eats input a line at a time. But if you want a wider outlook you need only script it.

So for every input line, if the current is `!` not the `$` last, `sed` appends the `N`ext line to pattern space as delimited by an intervening `\n`ewline character.

In the range expression, I first look for any match for *`ApplicationState`* followed by any `*` number of any `.` characters, followed by at least one `\n`ewline. To end the range expression I need to peek input - which is the purpose of the `$!N` in the first place. `sed` scans for the next occurrence of the line which would occur *after* the last you want to remove. It looks for a `\n`ewline followed by a pattern which should match the beginning of the next input block.

If that range expression is `!` not matched, `sed` will `P`rint up to the first occurring `\n`ewline in pattern space, and regardless of a match `sed` will afterward `D`elete up to the first occurring newline in pattern space and recycle to the top of the script with what remains.

Basically, `sed` slides over input 2 lines at a time, possibly `P`rinting the oldest one if it does not occur within your delete block, and always `D`eleting only the oldest one before appending the `N`ext.

Comment: Thanks @mikeserv That was the command that I was looking for!!

Comment: @OmarMorales - youre quite welcome - just next time try to make it the one you ask for as well. Its hard to guess at what people are looking for you know. But im glad i could help, and i hope it continues to work for you.

Comment: `sed -n '/\[ApplicationState\]/{:;n;/\[T114Base/!b;};p'`

Comment: @Costas - that's not legal in a lot of ways - i know that GNU does that weird thing with the empty label, but that scares me - `b` should actually branch *out*. I think it's bug - and I meant to file that report when I learned about it, but never did. Thank you for the reminder. Its that kind of stuff which makes requiring an *actual* null or newline to delimit such things perfectly ok w/ me.

Comment: OK, you free to use *non-empty label* `sed -n '/\[ApplicationState\]/{:test;n;/\[T114Base/!btest;};p'`

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually try?

Assuming you want to remove the whole line:

```
sed '/ApplicationState/d' inputfile
```

Comment: Yes... but actually I want to remove the whole block before the next header

Comment: Which block? If you don't tell us what you want, how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: Omar that comment should be an edit to your question